# add radio group by dynamically but radio button is xml

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

hi i have two radiobutton, i need to add radiogroup in dynamically.
how to do this?
this is my xml,thanks

```
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radiotwo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="b"
                        android:textSize="23dp" />
                   <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioone"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="a"
                        android:textSize="23dp" />
```

Comment: why don't you add radio group and radio buttons whole dynamically then ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the layout in witch you want to add it is a LinearLayout, you can add a RadioButton like this:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = findViewById(R.id.main);
RadioButton myButton = new RadioButton(this);
myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
myLayout.addView(myButton);
```